# MySQL - How get this result?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, sql-order-by

I have a two tables.
work:

```
+----+----------+
| id | position |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        1 |
|  2 |        2 |
+----+----------+
```

content:

```
+----+---------+------+-------------+
| id | work_id | name | translation |
+----+---------+------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 | Kot  |           1 |
|  2 |       1 | Cat  |           2 |
|  3 |       2 | Ptak |           1 |
|  4 |       2 | Bird |           2 |
|  5 |       2 | Ssss |           3 |
+----+---------+------+-------------+
```

I want to get result like this:

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | name | sortName |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | Kot  | NULL     |
|  1 | Cat  | NULL     |
|  2 | Ptak | Ssss     |
|  2 | Bird | Ssss     |
+----+------+----------+
```

My not working query is here:

```
select 
  w.id,
  c.name,
  cSort.name as sortName 
from 
  work w 
LEFT JOIN 
  content c 
ON
  (w.id=c.work_id) 
LEFT JOIN 
  content cSort 
ON
  (w.id=cSort.work_id) 
WHERE 
  c.translation IN(1,2) AND 
  cSort.translation=3 
ORDER BY 
  sortName
```

I want to get for each work at least one translation and secound if exist (translation=1 always exist). And for every row I want special column with translation used to sort. But Not always this translation exist for work.id. In this example I want to sort work by translation=3.

Sorry for my not fluent english. Any ideas?

Best regards

Comment: As to "My not working query": you should always tell us *what* doesn't work. E.g.: "The query shows other sortnames than expected and doesn't sort the results by work.position". (Explaining also helps you to look at the issues yourself again and you would probably have spot why the results are not ordered by work.position.)

Comment: this is an absurd data model

Answer (score 0):

So `translation` is also a `work_id` and you consider `translation` = 3 a translation in your example and `translation` <> 3 an original. You want to join each original record with every translation record where the latter's `work_id` matches the former's `translation`.

I think you are simply confusing IDs here. It should be `ON (w.translation = cSort.work_id)`.

Another way to write the query:

```
select o.work_id as id, o.name, t.name as sortname
from (select * from content where translation <> 3) o
left join (select * from content where translation = 3) t
  on t.work_id = o.translation
order by t.name;
```

There seems to be no need to join table `work`.

I'd like to add that the table design is a bit confusing. Somehow it is not clear from it what is a translation for what. In your example you interpret `translation` 3 as a translation for the non-three records, but this is just an example as you say. I don't find this readable.

**UPDATE:** In order to sort your results by work.position, you can join that table or use a subquery instead. Here is the `order by` clause for the latter:

```
order by (select position from work w where w.id = o.work_id);
```

Comment: It works but I get wrong result. Order is important. Look at my post what I except to get. With your query I get: id 2 | id 1 | id 1 | id 2 .

Comment: Okay, then the question is why you order by sortname in your query when you don't want to have your data ordered by sortname. I merely took that from your query. You don't even explain by what criteria you want your data ordered. It's probably the `position` from work table? I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
create table work ( id int, position int);
insert into work values
(  1 ,        1 ),
(  2 ,        2 );

create table content(id int, work_id int, name varchar(4), translation int);
insert into content values
(  1 ,       1 , 'Kot'  ,           1),
(  2 ,       1 , 'Cat'  ,           2), 
(  3 ,       2 , 'Ptak' ,           1), 
(  4 ,       2 , 'Bird' ,           2), 
(  5 ,       2 , 'Ssss' ,           3); 
*/
select  w.id,c.name,(select c.name from content c where c.work_id = w.id and c.translation = 3) sortname
from        work w
join        content c on w.id = c.work_id
where       c.translation <> 3;
```

result

```
+------+------+----------+
| id   | name | sortname |
+------+------+----------+
|    1 | Kot  | NULL     |
|    1 | Cat  | NULL     |
|    2 | Ptak | Ssss     |
|    2 | Bird | Ssss     |
+------+------+----------+
```